# Using -mno-cygwin option inside GCC 4.6

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cygwin, winexe

I am working on winexe project currently. winexe compiles windows C code on linux using -mno-cygwin as CFLAGS .

following is Makefile under directory winexesvc :-

```
CFLAGS=-mno-cygwin -Os
LDFLAGS=-mno-cygwin -s -Os

CC_WIN32 := $(shell bash -c 'which {i386,i586}-{mingw32,mingw32msvc}-gcc')
CC_WIN64 := $(shell bash -c 'which {x86_64,amd64}-{mingw32,mingw32msvc}-gcc')

all: winexesvc32_exe.c winexesvc64_exe.c

winexesvc32.exe: winexesvc32.o service32.o
    $(CC_WIN32) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

winexesvc64.exe: winexesvc64.o service64.o
    $(CC_WIN64) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%32.o: %.c
    $(CC_WIN32) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%64.o: %.c
    $(CC_WIN64) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

winexesvc32_exe.c: winexesvc32.exe bin2c.exe
    ./bin2c.exe winexesvc32_exe winexesvc32.exe > $@

winexesvc64_exe.c: winexesvc64.exe bin2c.exe
    ./bin2c.exe winexesvc64_exe winexesvc64.exe > $@

bin2c.exe: bin2c.c
    gcc -s -o $@ $^

clean:
    -@rm *.exe *.o *_exe.c
```

The entire code compiles and run successfully when no modification is done.

But,whenever I replace winexsvc.c file or winexesvc64_exe.c file or winexesvc32_exe.c 
(I need to modify these 3 files). It shows following error when I replace winexesvc.c with modified code. The modified code dosen't call any other file or any function outside the file.

So, the problem is when I do some modifications in above mentioned 3 files, I get above mentioned errors.
Any Idea why this is happening ?

P.S :- I have read other post regarding error of -mno-cygwin option in gcc.
but those are not relevant to my problem.
additional information :-
[I have got this from Makefile of winexesvc folder under winexe.]

Comment: what error(s) do you get? And get rid of that `-mno-cygwin`.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the errors you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :-
I used i586-mingw32msvc-gcc command along with suitable flags to compile every file by hand then linking it accordingly.

Got , the required results.